# Volley and symbol not found: AndroidHttpClient

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

I'm working on Android Studio on some one else's code that uses Volley.
I updated inside gradle to latest compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion (24) and targetSdkVersion.
Inside gradle configuration, volley was included in this way:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'
```

I migrated to:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.+'
```

I get some nasty 400 error, that should mean that the connection is done but it is for some reason wrong... then I found that inside Volley.java there's an error that I was not aware of, because it simply wasn't shown and the app was correctly compiled and run:

```
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
```

is in red and so is the subsequent call to a method in

```
AndroidHttpClient
```

(that fails with "symbol not found").

Now I have two questions:

1. how is it possible that I compile and run the application if there is an error in a library? I'm missing this.
2. how can I fix this, without moving to other network libraries?

Update:
to clarify, compiling to API 22 removes the error. compiling to API 24 creates this error that appears directly inside Volley's source. I would like to compile to API 24 without Volley, is it possible?

Comment: You can download the Volley source code and compile/modify it at your own risk ;)

Comment: You don't need `AndroidHttpClient` if you are using Volley, so I think you should show the code that is actually being used for `AndroidHttpClient`, since Volley probably isn't the problem here

Comment: I'm not using AndroidHttpClient, I'm using Volley.newRequestQueue(this), that contains AndroidHttpClient in its source code.

Comment: The reason the code is in red is because *you* can't build the code. The file AndroidHttpClient is indeed missing. But remember, *you* aren't building the library to use it in your app. You reference the JAR. And this JAR was built with the AndroidHttpClient present. Look at the source and you will see: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
                stack = new HurlStack();
            }` so it will never try to use AndroidHttpClient for API 24. Your build errors are something else.